# develop iphone app with phonegap and phonegap build for free

Tags: iphone, cordova, phonegap-build, code-signing-certificate

I have just started to learn phonegap in order to develop iphone application and publish it on the appstore but the first problem I encountered after I followed those commands :

```
phonegap create my-app
cd my-app
phonegap run ios
```

is : I must provide a signing key

and after some researchs I found out that it costs 99 per year

isn't it any free way to develop iphone app ?

thank you

Comment: Nop :) There s no way to publish an app to Appstore for free.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, if you want your app to be available in the App Store you will have to buy an iOS developers Account.

Comment: Yes, for this $99 per year Apple will provide access the to iTunes Connect where you can upload your app to the App Store.

Comment: @begiPass $99 + TAX and extra charges if you are register A/c outside of United States :x